# Implementing TryFrom trait to accept both consumed Vec and non-consumed refs

Tags: rust

I have an existing library code with `TryFrom<Vec<f64>>` implementation that consumes the `Vec` struct on conversion, e.g. `Bounds::try_from(vec![1., 2., 3., 4.])`.  Without breaking backwards compatibility, I would like it to also support other values like these:

- `Bounds::try_from(&[1., 2., 3., 4.])`
- `Bounds::try_from(&[1., 2., 3., 4.].as_slice())`
- `Bounds::try_from([1., 2., 3., 4.])` -- this one is optional, but nice

Is this possible with the Into/IntoIterator/... traits / generic restrictions?  All my attempts didn't work out.

```rust
impl TryFrom<Vec<f64>> for Bounds {
    type Error = ParseBoundsError;

    /// Parse four f64 values as a Bounds value, same order as the [Bounds::new] constructor.
    fn try_from(value: Vec<f64>) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        if value.len() == 4 {
            Ok(Self {
                left: value[0],
                bottom: value[1],
                right: value[2],
                top: value[3],
            })
        } else {
            Err(BadLen)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with multiple individual impls, e.g.

```
// this gives us TryFrom<[f64; 4]> for free
impl From<[f64; 4]> for Bounds {
    fn from(value: [f64; 4]) -> Self {
        Self {
            left: value[0],
            bottom: value[1],
            right: value[2],
            top: value[3],
        }
    }
}
impl TryFrom<Vec<f64>> for Bounds {
    type Error = ParseBoundsError;

    fn try_from(value: Vec<f64>) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        let arr: [f64; 4] = value.try_into().map_err(|_| BadLen)?;
        Ok(arr.into())
    }
}
impl TryFrom<&'_ [f64]> for Bounds {
    type Error = ParseBoundsError;

    fn try_from(value: &[f64]) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        let arr: [f64; 4] = value.try_into().map_err(|_| BadLen)?;
        Ok(arr.into())
    }
}
```

You might think the following would work to summarise the impls on `Vec` and slices and more, but unfortunately this clashes with our specific array impl, because `[f64;4] : TryInto<[f64;4]>`, so we can't do that (but maybe we will using [specialization](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1210-impl-specialization.html)?)

```
// this gives us TryFrom<[f64; 4]> for free
impl From<[f64; 4]> for Bounds {
    // same as before
}
// Fails because T can be [f64;4], and we already have an impl TryFrom<[f64;4]> for Bounds (free from the above impl)
impl<T: TryInto<[f64; 4]>> TryFrom<T> for Bounds {
    type Error = ParseBoundsError;

    fn try_from(value: Vec<f64>) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        let arr: [f64; 4] = value.try_into().map_err(|_| BadLen)?;
        Ok(arr.into())
    }
}
```

Solutions leveraging IntoIterator hit a similar snag, because there's already a blanket `impl<T, U> TryFrom<U> for T where U: Into<T>`. I think in the case of two blanket impls of the same trait, the compiler cannot rule out the case where something satisfies the bounds of both impls. In this case, that would be something is both `Into<Bounds>` and `IntoIterator<Item = f64>`.

```
// error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::TryFrom<_>` for type `Bounds`
impl<I: IntoIterator<Item = f64>> TryFrom<I> for Bounds {
    type Error = ParseBoundsError;

    fn try_from(value: I) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        let it: [f64; 4] = value.into_iter().collect().try_into().map_err(|_| BadLen)?;
        Ok(Self {
            left: value[0],
            bottom: value[1],
            right: value[2],
            top: value[3],
        })
    }
}
```

I think the above restriction will get in the way of any blanket implementations of TryFrom, unfortunately, perhaps until we have specialization.

Comment: Which TryFrom variants are recommended for for implementation in a generic library like the above? Thx!

Comment: Disclaimer: I've not published any rust libraries, and I'm not confident in the best practices here.

Comment: I'd probably make sure to cover at least `[f64;4]`, `&[f64]`, and `T where T: Iterator<[f64]>`. After that, if the API user doesn't have a direct conversion, they can usually at least go through one of the options you provided. Others to do for convenience would be `Vec<f64>`, and maybe variations of the above that take by reference instead of ownership.

Comment: It's too late to edit my comment, but I just noticed a typo: I meant `T where T: Iterator<f64>`, and not `T where T: Iterator<[f64]>`

Comment: Hmm, somehow I am not able to implement this - I get a conflict with core. Plus I am not certain which Iterator you mean -- I only see `std::iter::Iterator<Item=f64>` ?

Comment: Ah you're right. I had forgotten that it would not work for `Iterator` for the same reason it will not work for `IntoIterator`. I wrote this without testing it on my end, and I'm glad the compiler can catch this.